# Serialize/Deserialize file linux, cat

Tags: linux, serialization, base64, cat

Is there any simple command to serialize and deserialize file using base64 for example.

I want to quick move small file less that 1 mb from one server to another using console (ssh)

How to cat this file on first server using base64 encode.
and cat >> example.file to file on another server using base64 decode?

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Requests for cmd-line usage of utilities,  tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `base64`. It is a part of `coreutils` package in debian linux.

[man base64](https://linux.die.net/man/1/base64)